# Cannot delete AVDs or create new AVD in Android device manager due to "incompatible JDK"

Tags: java, android, xamarin, incompatibility

Am trying to make a mobile game with xamarin/monogame using an android emulator.

I have a virtual Pixel 5 (API 30) created in android device manager that launches fine but refuses to be deployed to, so I tried to delete it and create another.

Deletion returns error message saying that the AVD can't be deleted because I have an incompatible JDK, please install Microsoft OpenJDK...
The website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/openjdk) the error message points me to tells me that Microsoft's OJDK is automatically installed if you selected the android SDK packages when installing visual studio community, which I did. Reinstalled this package and the error persists.

I have tried:

Manually downloading ODJK 18, 17, 11, and 8, and extracting to C:\Program Files\Android\jdk, then pointing Xamarin to the file path. I even ran "java -version" in Android adb command prompt, and it tells me that I do indeed have the JDKs installed. This is what it returns:

openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS

OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-30338 (build 17.0.2+8-LTS)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-30338 (build 17.0.2+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

I have also tried reinstalling VSC 2019 and it didn't work.

Other info: Initially the file location for the "automatically installed from android SDK package's ODJK" was under something called Eclipse foundation in C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation. I moved the only file in this folder (jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot) to C:\Program Files\Android\jdk and set that as Xamarin's JDK location, restarted vsc, and tried again, to no avail.

Comment: But how did you create the first Pixel 5 (API 30)? In addition, had you done everything following the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/windows)? Finally, ensure there is only one jdk in the jdk folder.

Comment: You can also try the solution in this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/issues-creating-android-emulator/1467306).

Comment: I made the first Pixel 5 after Android Device Manager prompted me to after I launched it for the first time, with no issues. I can't remember what changed between then and now. I set up everything as the official doc instructed, and I tried putting only 1 JDK in the JDK folder. I have another question now- is simply downloading a JDK, unzipping it, and moving it to the JDK folder how you're supposed to get and use a new JDK? I saw some articles describing "installing" a JDK into a java folder by running a .exe.

Comment: Also tried the solution in the second link. Both locations, the "C:\program files\java folder" and the "C:\program files\android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25" folder, do not work.
Note: I did have to manually create the "microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25" under the jdk folder.

Comment: Maybe you can change the Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> JDK Locations to another folder which has a new JDK to use a new JDK.